# Is there any way to set fieldPermissions in the Admin.profile to be able to edit and read all fields for development purposes?

Tags: api, administration, custom-field

I would like to set fieldPermissions in the Admin.profile to be able to edit and read all fields for development purposes.
Something like this:

```
<fieldPermissions>
    <editable>true</editable>
    <field>*</field>
    <readable>true</readable>
</fieldPermissions>
```

But I am a not aware of a way that it can be done. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the metadata xml for the Admin profile and for fieldPermissions find and replace the

```
<editable>false</editable> to <editable>true</editable>
```

and

```
<readable>false</readable> to <readable>true</readable>
```

Finally save the changes back to server.

This solution worked for me.